# VS 2010: LNK1104 - cannot create import library

Tags: visual-studio-2010

After porting a medium sized C/C++ application with a few libraries to VS 2010, I am getting the following error (Configuration: Debug, Platform: Win32):

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 
'D:\projects\Libraries\SDL_image-1.2.7\VC10\Debug\Win32\SDL_image.lib'
```

I have quadruple checked SDL_net project settings in VS 2010. The folder name is correct, there are no folders containing blanks anywhere in the entire solution, etc. The DLL's object files are all in that folder (as they should be). Yet the import library cannot be created. This stuff works fine in VS 2008.

There are other similarly setup libraries in the solution (like SDL_mixer, SDL_net) and I don't have this problem with them.

How can I possibly fix this?

Comment: I could resolve this issue by removing the project from the solution and re-converting the VS 2008 project. Now the problem is however that VS 2010 doesn't automatically resolve library dependencies even when I manually set the dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

Check the **vcxproj** file - it seems like VS2010 adds reference to the project it self. I found following section at the end:

```
<ItemGroup> 
  <ProjectReference Include="XXXXXXXX.vcxproj">
    <Project>{00e4326ce-9477-46e2-9133-43566aeec84e}</Project>
    <ReferenceOutputAssembly>false</ReferenceOutputAssembly>
  </ProjectReference>  
</ItemGroup>
```

Where `XXXXX` is the project name. After removing it everything went fine.